# System tray icon in node.js application

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, icons, system-tray

This is what I need in my node.js application:

- System tray icon
- changing this icon during application work
- menu after clicking on icon
- creation of windows with fields for login / password and confirmation buttons

This is what I found:

- https://github.com/appjs/appjs - It looks good, but there is still no system tray support (it looks it will be done in some time)
- https://github.com/zcbenz/node-gui - It looks there is support for all I need, but I can't install it (I think this project is dead...)

Do you have any recommendations? I need something **reliable**, **easy to install** and as **cross-system** as possible.

//edit

**Since 6th November Appjs has basic tray icon support.**

Comment: How did you solve this? I'm having almost the same use case, thinking of using now oldish node-qt.

Answer (score 11):

For anyone else that lands up here, check out https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit - a great package that allows you to create desktop applications using your favourite tools like JavaScript, with support for native shell access, tray icons and a lot more.

Update:
The app has moved to [NWjs.io](http://nwjs.io) but it's the same brilliant concept.

Comment: I've since built a production-level application using Node-Webkit, it's truly awesome. One program that works on Windows and Mac OS, with tray integration - all done via JavaScript!

Comment: You should also check out the direct competitor of NW.js, Electron: http://electron.atom.io/

Comment: Indeed, Electron has become quite popular as well, it's a good option to consider.

Answer (score 4):

I've used [systray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/systray) on Linux. It is promised to work on macOS and Windows too. But I didn't tested it.

Example from official docs:

```
import SysTray from 'systray'

const systray = new SysTray({
    menu: {
        // you should using .png icon in macOS/Linux, but .ico format in windows
        icon: "<base64 image string>",
        title: "标题",
        tooltip: "Tips",
        items: [{
            title: "aa",
            tooltip: "bb",
            // checked is implement by plain text in linux
            checked: true,
            enabled: true
        }, {
            title: "aa2",
            tooltip: "bb",
            checked: false,
            enabled: true
        }, {
            title: "Exit",
            tooltip: "bb",
            checked: false,
            enabled: true
        }]
    },
    debug: false,
    copyDir: true, // copy go tray binary to outside directory, useful for packing tool like pkg.
})
 
systray.onClick(action => {
    if (action.seq_id === 0) {
        systray.sendAction({
            type: 'update-item',
            item: {
            ...action.item,
            checked: !action.item.checked,
            },
            seq_id: action.seq_id,
        })
    } else if (action.seq_id === 1) {
        // open the url
        console.log('open the url', action)
    } else if (action.seq_id === 2) {
        systray.kill()
    }
})
```

It does not provide

> creation of windows with fields for login / password and confirmation buttons

But this task is a separate one in my opinion. So this answer can be helpful for other people who just want systray icon.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at Node-QT (https://github.com/arturadib/node-qt) maybe that can help.

Comment: 1) how to run it in system tray 2) when windows boot how to let it always run in tray?