# Creating system tray icons with Node

Tags: node.js

I'm looking for an NPM package that:

- Lets me create a system tray icon with context menu
- Works on Windows, Mac and Linux
- Plays well with TypeScript *(Electron gave me compilation errors in `node_modules/electron/electron.d.ts`)*
- Is compatible with Node 12+
- Doesn't require me to write a browser app like the Tray APIs of Electron and Nw.js seem to
- Works independently of any non-NPM dependencies (unlike node-qt)

I have already looked at [System tray icon in node.js application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12979727/system-tray-icon-in-node-js-application) and none of the suggestions there seem to check the boxes, so I don't consider this a duplicate.

Are there any packages that match the requirements?